# How to output MySQL version with DB::raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I struggle extracting the MySQL version using Laravel's `DB::raw` query. I currently tried:

```
$mysql_version = DB::raw('SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";');
dd($mysql_version);
```

The output I receive looks like:

```
Expression {#724 ▼
  #value: "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I retrieve the MySQL version successfully?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with that:

```
select version()
```

Comment: `DB::raw('select version()');` returns Expression {#724 ▼
  #value: "select version()". Basically the same output :-(
}

Comment: `DB::select( DB::raw("select version()") );` solved the issue! Thanks a lot!